# How to ignore saving duplicate records before inserting to database and continue saving other non-duplicate records using vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I have to import or copy the records from one database to another. My problem is it continuously insert records even if they are already existing. I want to control inserting duplicate records. I want them to be ignored and only those records that are not existing in database will be inserted. Any suggestion or modification in my code is highly appreciated. Thank you.

```vb
Dim con1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= database1.accdb")
Dim con2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= database2.accdb")

con2.Open()
Dim CompQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sampletable WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName"
Dim compCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(CompQuery, con2)
compCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "FirstName")
compCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "LastName")

If Convert.ToInt32(compCommand.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 Then
    'ignoring duplicate entries msgbox("Some records fail to save because it would create duplicate entries!")
    Exit Sub
Else

    'Create the data adapter with a SelectCommand using the first connection.
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM table1 ", con1)
    'Add the InsertCommand with the second connection. 
    da.InsertCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO sampletable (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)", con2)
    'Add the insert parameters.                                                                                                 
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirsfName", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "FirstName")
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "LastName")
               'Keep the records in a state where they can be inserted into the destination table.
    da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'Get the data from the source database.
    da.Fill(dt)
    'Save the data to the destination database.
    da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Data Added!")

    con1.Dispose()
    con2.Dispose()

End If
```

Comment: Filter out the duplicates with your select statement. Simply select the records from table1 where they don't exist in sampletable.